# Using PictureBox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I'm current using the following Code for loading images onto the picture box.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Desert;
```

I would replace "Desert" with a 'Variable' for the the code would work as follows.

```
String Image_Name;
Imgage_Name = "Desert";
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image_Name;
```

I have a lot of Imagines which I need to load and want to use a Variable for the image name instead of having to write a separate line for each image. Is this Possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the resources .. something like this:

```
using System.Collections;

string image_name = "Desert";

foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true)) {
    if ((string)kvp.Key == image_name) {
        var bmp = kvp.Value as Bitmap;
        if (bmp != null) {
            // bmp is your image
        }
    }
}
```

You could wrap it in a nice little function.. something like this:

```
public Bitmap getResourceBitmapWithName(string image_name) {
    foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true)) {
        if ((string)kvp.Key == image_name) {
            var bmp = kvp.Value as Bitmap;
            if (bmp != null) {
                return bmp;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var resourceBitmap = getResourceBitmapWithName("Desert");
if (resourceBitmap != null) {
    pictureBox1.Image = resourceBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.
If I may, What is 'kvp' ?

Comment: I named it `kvp` because it represents a "Key-Value Pair". A dictionary item.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Programatically using a string as object name when instantiating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314008/programatically-using-a-string-as-object-name-when-instantiating-an-object). By default, C# does not allow you to do that. But you can still use a `string` to access the image you want from a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90.aspx).

You can try something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Image> nameAndImg = new Dictionary<string, Image>()
{
    {"pic1",  Properties.Resources.pic1},
    {"pic2",  Properties.Resources.pic2}
    //and so on...
};

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = textBox1.Text;

    if (nameAndImg.ContainsKey(name))
        pictureBox1.Image = nameAndImg[name];

    else
        MessageBox.Show("Inavlid picture name");
}
```