# How to maintain a list of character occurrences in a sentence and which word they were in

Tags: c#

I want to build a program that analyses sentences, and then for each character/number/symbol that appears in the words of the sentence, record which words the character appears in.  (upper/lower case to be ignored, and duplicate entries of a character in a word are ignored).

So if I had the sentence "I wandered lonely as a cow".

1. After the first word, i'd have a data construct... i - 1;   // because "I" occurred in the first word.
2. after the second word, my data construct would be... i - 1; w - 2; a - 2;  n - 2; d - 2; e - 2; r - 2;
3. after the sixth word...  i - 1; w - 2,6; a - 2,4,5; n - 2,3; d - 2; e - 2,3; r - 2; l - 3; o - 3,6; y - 3; s - 4; c - 6;

This is to be in c#.  I've considered a 2d array, 26 (for the letters) x 20 (words in a sentence.  The issue here is that my array is going to be sparse, and its also going to be hard work keeping track of which element is the next spare one against each letter.  I'd want my array for the letter a to be [2,4,5] not [0,2,0,4,5] or [0,0,2,0,4,5], Its also complicated by wanting to cater for other symbols, so the 26 will get bigger quickly.  The third of those arrays is the one that is "obvious" how to program, but is the least elegant solution.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] sentence = new string[6] { "i", "wandered", "lonely", "as", "a", "cow" };
            string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            int[,] letterInWord= new int[26, 7];

            for (int letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < alphabet.Length; letterIndex++)
            {
                for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < sentence.Length; wordIndex++)
                {
                    if(sentence[wordIndex].IndexOf(alphabet[letterIndex]) >= 0)
                    {
                        letterInWord[letterIndex, wordIndex+1] = wordIndex+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            // then analyse or just print out (adding 1 to get counting base 1)
            for (int letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < alphabet.Length; letterIndex++)
            {
                Console.Write(alphabet[letterIndex]+ " is in word(s) " );
                for (int wordIndex = 1; wordIndex <= sentence.Length; wordIndex++)
                {
                    if (letterInWord[letterIndex, wordIndex] > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(letterInWord[letterIndex, wordIndex]  + " ");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

So, that works, but I just don't like it.

Ideally i'd want a list for the sentence called sentenceList, and then for each letter i find (e.g. z), I'd look in sentenceList for a list called listForZ, and if i didnt find it, I'd create a new list called listForZ, add the word number to the List, and add listForZ into the sentenceList.

But that requires programmatically creating the name of the list from the variable I've just found in the word, and I've struggled to understand how that would work.  I suppose I could use a factory method pattern which IS aware of all the listnames I could have and creates them appropriately, but again, that seems overkill for what I want.

Any suggested directions?

Comment: Hi! At this site, we require you to at least try to solve the problem yourself first. As it is the question is too broad. Try to solve this yourself and when you run into a problem, add your code as [mcve] and explain in detail what is not working as you intend.

Comment: Unless you are required to use arrays, look at some the Collections available in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections.

Comment: @esko - I've got the program working with the 3rd version of the array above, its just a horrible solution, and I'm after a more elegant solution.  I know I can get the first array version working with a separate structure holding the "next position for insert", but that looks ugly too.

Comment: If you want help with your approach, **EDIT** your post above and show us your current **CODE**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But that requires programmatically creating the name of the list from
>   the variable I've just found in the word, and I've struggled to
>   understand how that would work.

Using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2), you can associate a **key** with a **value**.  In your case, the characters in the words are the keys, and the word positions where they occur are the values:

```
Dictionary<char, List<int>> occurrences = new Dictionary<char, List<int>>();

string sentence = "I wandered lonely as a cow";
string[] words = sentence.ToLower().Split(" ".ToCharArray());
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    foreach(char c in words[i].ToCharArray().Distinct())
    {
        if (!occurrences.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            occurrences.Add(c, new List<int>());
        }
        occurrences[c].Add(i + 1);
    }
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<char, List<int>> kvp in occurrences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key.ToString() + " - " + String.Join(",", kvp.Value.ToArray()));
}
```

Output generated:

```
i - 1
w - 2,6
a - 2,4,5
n - 2,3
d - 2
e - 2,3
r - 2
l - 3
o - 3,6
y - 3
s - 4
c - 6
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks the closest to what I envisaged, I eventually found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314008/programatically-using-a-string-as-object-name-when-instantiating-an-object) answer which is the same idea (you're in good company).

Answer (score 0):

With a help of *regular expressions* (we have to match words) and *Linq* to query these words you can implement something like this:

```
string sentence = "I wandered lonely as a cow";

var result = string.Join("; ", Regex
  .Matches(sentence, "[A-Za-z]+")  // Word is a sequence of A..Z a..z letters
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select((match, index) => new {
    word = match.Value.ToLower(),  // So we have word, e.g. "lonely" 
    index + 1                      // and its index, e.g. "3"  
  })
  .SelectMany(item => item.word.Select(c => new {
    character = c,             // for each character 
    wordNumber = item.index    // we have a index of the word(s) where it appears
  }))
  .GroupBy(item => item.character, item => item.wordNumber) // grouping by character
  .Select(chunk => $"{chunk.Key} - {string.Join(",", chunk.Distinct().OrderBy(n => n))}"));

// Let's have a look at the results
Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
i - 1; w - 2,6; a - 2,4,5; n - 2,3; d - 2; e - 2,3; r - 2; l - 3; o - 3,6; y - 3; s - 4; c - 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "I wandered lonely as a cow";

            string pattern = @"(?'word'\w+)\s*";

            string[] words = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["word"].Value).ToArray();

            var results = words
                .Select(x => new { word = x, characters = x.ToCharArray().Select((y, i) => new { ch = y, index = i }).GroupBy(y => y.ch).Select(y => y.First()).ToList() }).ToList();

        }
    }

}
```